Movie featuring AI super villain
I seem to remember a trailer a while ago advertising a movie in which there was a male humanoid terminator-like AI android who had escaped from a lab and the movie revolved around trying to kill him or capture him. Maybe this movie is still not released. Trying to figure out what it is.
This is a movie that is either coming up or released recently (last 2 years).
The android is created by the military I think and I think they send some blade runner type guy to try to hunt it down when it gets loose.

Can you give more details of the AI android because there are a lot of movies with similar elements.

Without more details, it makes me think of Russell Crowe's first (terrible) movie, Virtuosity. https://youtu.be/kJeASglM54w

@BrettFromLA Yes, it was like that except a more recent movie.

Did it look low-budget? (There's a ton of cheap sci-fi released every year.) And are you 100% sure it was a trailer and not some short movie online?

Sounds like chappie http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1823672/ or the remake of Robocop http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1234721/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

Actually I think it isn't a movie, I think you are remembering the somewhat awesome looking "prototype" trailer




You got it! That's it! Nice. Why do you say it's not a movie? In my question I specifically say it might be an upcoming movie, which apparently is what it is.

Ah I should probably clarify, I was trying to keep track of this film myself but its been awfully quiet,
The film was originally a proof of concept trailer that was due ot be made into a film, but I've heard very little concerning it since seeing it. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2223842/
